# Ajax does not 'find' input fields

Tags: jquery, ajax

Ok... just spent way too much time working this out...
running jQuery 1.9 or better....

I am wondering if there is a better solution.

---

I am building a WebApp with FORMS dependant on FORMS....

1. Page opens and shows the first FORM...
2. Users make some selections on the first FORM, clicks on the jQuery/ajax (not html) Submit button,  that FORM is processed and the jQuery/Ajax updates the page and replaces the first FORM with the second FORM... everything worked as expected. (level 1)
3. Users make some selections on the second FORM, clicks on the jQuery/ajax (not html) Submit button,  that FORM is processed and the jQuery/Ajax updates the page and replaces the second FORM with the third FORM... everything worked as expected. (level 2)

4  Users make some selections on the third FORM, clicks on the jQuery/ajax (not html) Submit button,  that FORM is processed and the jQuery/Ajax updates the page  (level 3) and....

The input fields (all checkboxes) and all their properties are now clearly visible in the DOM via Firebug... but jQuery cannot "find" the input fields... to load the var thisData = {} object.

Using this syntax...

```
var search4 = $('#search4').val(); 
var search4 = $('form#updateTickets input#search4').val(); 
var search4 = $('form#updateTickets:input#search4').val();
```

None of these or some other complex selectors work when run on level three in the WebApp... 
but they all work just fine tested on the first level in my test page.

---

My solution was to catch and store the input field values in global variables when the jQuery FORM validation script ran before Submit on level two.... which is really a very simple thing to do... just a couple more lines of code and a little shuffle in the logic.

As I said... I was wondering if there is a 'better way'....

If not... maybe this saves somebody else a couple of hours of trying to find a workable solution.

---

EDITED....
@Ashley Medway and others...

onclick in the FORM =>  submitAJAXForm( num, action, id){ ....

```
var ajaxURL  = AjaxPath + "AirTrafficControl/mysqlContacts.php";  
            var thisDataType = "html";              

            var search1 = $('#search1').val();
            var search2 = $('#search2').val();              
            var search3 = $('#search3').val();
            var search4 = $('#search4').val();

            var action1 = 1;            

            var thisData = {                    
                thisTable: '<?php echo $thisTable; ?>',                             
                action: action,
                action1: action1,                   
                company_id: search1,                
                company_zipcode1: search2,
                company_city1: search3,
                companyname: search4,   
                ajax: ajax,                                             
                submit: true };
```

then the rest of the standard jQuery Ajax stuff...
Ajax works fine... just doesn't pick up the four ( $search1, #search2, #search3, #search4 ) input fields...

NO IFrames, NO duplicate IDs...  code works perfectly on the stand-along test page.... just doesn't work when buried in the WebApp....

Comment: Please show some more relevant code. When do you try to access your fields?

Comment: How you call Ajax? for example you have a function which will be call after on submit button clicked? or what?

Comment: can you confirm you are not using iframes and that you are not repeating form ids? can you also confirm you are using ids in you inputs and not just name? if you could show some code it would be easier to find whats going on

Comment: Don't you use jquery's ON or LIVE functions?

Comment: What is the output of $('#search4').length in Firebug?

Comment: ^not using ON or LIVE in this WebApp

Comment: ^either '' if checked == false or 1 if checked == true

Comment: So, In my view point the problem is because of not to use live or on functions. Could you please try to call your ajax function in live or on function? If you are using jquery 1.7 + please use on function

Comment: You say you have multiple checkboxes. Do they all have distinct IDs?

Comment: @Ali... ok... post that line of code that replaces...onClick="submitAJAXForm(3,'.$action.',\''.$ticket_id.'\');"

Comment: @akhikhi... as stated above... all of the IDs are unique.. only using them one time each.